# How to run Conky from terminal?

Tags: command-line, conky

In this [Unixmen tutorial](http://www.unixmen.com/configure-conky-lua-in-ubuntu-11-10-12-04-fedora-debian-and-linuxmint-howto-conky/) there are 11 steps to setup Conky; I did all of them but the terminal show this message:

```
The program 'conky' can be found in the following packages:
         * conky-cli
         * conky-std
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I then try this but saw this message:

```
ismail@ismail-ASUS:~$ sudo apt-get install conky
[sudo] password for ismail: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Probably Ubuntu Software Center or Synaptic is already open. If so, close those programs, and retry.

If nothing changes, close the session (log out) or reboot and retry.

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure Software Center or synaptic are not running, if necessary, you can do

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

and retry, which will work, but it's not recommended. Do it if you cant restart right now.

I'd say you restart or log in again and retry.

Answer (score -1):

The error means dpkg is running. If you run `sudo killall dpkg` (or `sudo killall -9 dpkg` when the first command complains about not being able to kill dpkg) then it will be fixed.

BUT: This is not the 'clean' method of stopping `dpkg` down !

Some background first:
dpkg is the 'real' package manager of ubuntu. Apt, apt-get, synaptic, ... are all frontends. If you close all this frontends then the error will also be gone (in a clean way)